# How to describe the if condition in a more efficient way in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, rhino

I am doing check on three different variables which are holding array of strings like below.

```
var a = ["ghi",dwe"]
var b = ["ghsj"]
var c = ["gdjr"]
var result; // result array
```

I am checking each time if variable a,b,c are not undefined and if they are holding some value
I am simply pushing a string for each variable in the result array.

Below is line of code for same.

```
    if(a !== undefined && a.length > 0) {

    result.push("Astring");

}

if(b !== undefined && b.length > 0) {
    result.push("Bstring");

}

if(c!== undefined && c.length > 0) {
    result.push("Cstring");
}
```

Expected Result should be if the var a,b,c are defined and non empty then **result** array variable should hold value like below

```
["Astring","BString","CString"]
```

Is there a more efficient way of describing this code.Here I am just checking
each and every variable using if condition. Also , I am restricted in some ways as I am using a Rhino js engine ver 1.7.12.

Comment: Store `a`, `b` and `c` in an array, then you can iterate over said array, check if present and non-empty, and call your action.

Comment: How we can differ what result needs to be pushed. Because for var A if non empty ->"A" needs to be pushed  and in similar way for other variables.

Comment: Ah, I see. Let me modify my answer, 1 sec...

Answer (score 1):

You could create an object with your initial data. Then iterate over it, and append the key (e.g. `a`, `b` or `c`) if it matches your condition.

Here's a quick demo:

```js
// Initial Data
const a = ['ghi', 'dwe'];
const b = ['ghsj'];
const c = ['gdjr'];

// Store intial within an array
const abc = {a, b, c};

const result = [];

// Append each data item that present, is array, and not empty
Object.keys(abc).forEach((letterKey) => {
  const content = abc[letterKey];
  if(Array.isArray(content) && content.length > 0) {
    result.push(letterKey);
  }
});

// Print results
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an object instead of an array, so that the result-elements can be specified.

```js
var a = ["ghi","dwe"]
var b = ["ghsj"]
var c = ["gdjr"]

mapping = {
    "AString": a,
    "BString": b,
    "CString": c
}
var result = []; // result array
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(mapping)) {
    if (value !== undefined && value.length > 0) {
        result.push(key)
    }
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

first you will store the 3 variables in a list then you loop over them with map

```
var a = ["ghi","dwe"]
var b = ["ghsj"]
var c = ["gdjr"]
var result = [];

let list = [a,b,c]

list.map(item => {
    if(item !== undefined && a.length > 0) {
        result.push(item)
    }
})
```

Comment: this may not be supported in Rhino JS version 1.7.12.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most efficient way is a raw `for` loop.

```
var a = ["ghi","dwe"]
var b = ["ghsj"]
var c = ["gdjr"]
var result = [];

const items = [a,b,c]
const itemCount = items.length
let resultingItems = []
for (let i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
    if(items[i] !== undefined && items[i].length > 0) {
        resultingItems .push(items[i])
}
```

Raw `for` loop might be more efficient as the `map` function creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

Comment: "*Raw `for` loop might be more efficient*" - [no](https://youtu.be/m9cTaYI95Zc?t=951)

Comment: thanks for the insight. the video he compares the different "fors", foreach, for of or raw for, `for (const i=0; i < lenght; i++)`. My comment was regarding `for` vs `map`. Isn't applying a function to each of the elements and populationg a new arraw more expensive?

Comment: `map` is optimised in the same way as `forEach` in that regard. It's not doing a different thing either: `resultingItems = []` is creating a new array, and `resultingItems.push(…)` is populating it, just as `map` would.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is for you to define a function:

```js
var a = ["ghi","dwe"];
var b = [];
var c = ["gdjr"];
var result = [];

function pushToResult(variable, value){
  if(typeof variable != 'undefined' && variable.length > 0)
    result.push(value)
}

pushToResult(a, "Astring");
pushToResult(b, "Bstring");
pushToResult(c, "Cstring");

console.log(result);
```

If you want push the variable name into the result, then:

```js
var a = ["ghi","dwe"];
var b = [];
var c = ["gdjr"];
var result = [];

function pushToResult(variable, value){
  if(typeof variable != 'undefined' && variable.length > 0)
    result.push(value)
}

pushToResult(a, Object.keys({a})[0]);
pushToResult(b, Object.keys({b})[0]);
pushToResult(c, Object.keys({c})[0]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Use `Object.keys(…)[0]` instead of `Object.keys(…).pop()`